# Security risks with enabling CORS

Tags: php, security, cakephp, cors

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.8 and I'd like to enable CORS for a few of my actions to be able to process requests made from other domains. I have a payment processor that uses webooks, and I would like to utilize that functionality, in addition to other features I'd like to use.

This is a two part question

1. If I enable CORS on a specific function, does that mean that function is the **only** one that will accept requests from other domains (assuming it's the only function that it's enabled for)?

For example, say I have the following actions/methods...

```
public function cors_enabled(){
    $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    echo "other domains can access this";
}

public function cors_not_enabled(){
    echo "good luck getting this content!";
}
```

If someone from another domain tried to access the "cors_enabled" function they would see the "other domains can access this!" message, but if they tried to access the "cors_not_enabled" function it wouldn't be allowed. Is this correct?

2. Assuming I know exactly what I'm looking for in POST/GET data and validate against it, are there any major security risks I face? Yes, other domains can access the particular URL, but assuming I have proper validation and I know exactly what I'm looking for, are there any other factors I need to consider?

Comment: Define what is CORS ??? Not everyone knows CORS meaning

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird This isn't auto-mechanics for dummies, this is StackOverflow, we're programmers, and CORS is a very well-known technique, and if someone doesn't know what it is, well, the question has [**the cors tag**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cors/info) set that explains what it is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you do not have the specific header that enable CORS:
   `$this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`
   The CORS will be disabled and other domains won't be able to connect.

   2. If you put some authorization token in your POST data and then process this token in your code, then it is safe for the endpoint to stay open.
      However this token should not be static otherwise it is not secure in the long run.
      The usual practice is to hash the timestamp with some salt and use it as authorization token.

Comment: this is browser behavior to block making request to cross origin.And if it is POST request, the browser makes pre-flight to Corss server and check if the server has the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header or not. Allowing * is not good to go. it allows to all domain, you can restrict to the target domain who can post to your application buy that you can narrow the attack surface.

Comment: @AntoanMilkov , so is that a yes that only functions/methods with CORS enabled will be able to be accessed from other domains, and those without it enabled won't be? I wasn't sure if enabling it in one method somehow enables it site-wide.

Comment: @PankajDey that's a good point. Just so I understand (for learning purposes), suppose I know exactly what I'm looking for in the requests. If I leave it open to all domains (meaning `"*"`) and validate the incoming requests, is that any less safe? For example, say I expect a POST value of "dog." If someone sends a post request with "cat" I wouldn't allow the request, but if "dog" is sent then I would continue to sanitize and process the request.

Comment: Cors allows csrf attacks. If allowing all is the necessary part, we need to go for anti forgery token. As it is almost same concept of above.

Comment: @user3476345 Yes it is safe, but make sure that the value 'dog' is different for each request and that nobody has means to guess the exact value. Ask if you need more help. Also read about CSRF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery